# No match for argument: subversion

Tags: unix, redhat, yum, rhel

I'm using the [`redhat/ubi8`](https://hub.docker.com/r/redhat/ubi8) image in docker.

Docker version is 20.10.8, build 3967b7d.

I tried to run `yum update` and `upgrade` without success:

```sh
# yum search svn
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
    
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    
Last metadata expiration check: 2:20:45 ago on Wed Sep  1 06:28:43 2021.
No matches found.
    
# yum search subversion
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
    
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    
Last metadata expiration check: 2:21:06 ago on Wed Sep  1 06:28:43 2021.
No matches found.
```

How should I do to add `yum` repository for SVN?

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read from the error messages your system is not registered in RHN. You should first register the system and then you will be install packages from RHEL repo. Check [this atricle](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273)

Comment: can i add `yum` repository for SVN without registered? i can `yum install` other app. for example git